# air mobile controls

Tags: user-interface, mobile, air, adobe, flash-builder

Having downloaded Flashbuilder 4.5 it seems there are very few spark mobile controls available at the moment - no datepicker , not even a combobox. Is there a third party resource for such items? Does Adobe have plans to make a more complete set available?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both of your questions is yes, I'm pretty sure Adobe is going to make a fuller set of controls for mobile eventually and also there are 3rd party providers already gearing up for mobile, [Flextras](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm) for example (who is an active SO member btw) is definitely on the case judging by his blog: https://www.flextras.com/blog/